# Can a mean & variance computation algorithm in Python be implemented recursively using the divide and conquer approach?

Tags: python, data-science, divide-and-conquer

A recursive mean computation using D&C is easy when the length of a list is known beforehand.

```
def mv_recursive (X):
    if len(X)==1:
        mu = X[0]
        var = 0
    else:
        mu = (int(len(X)/2)/len(X))*mv_recursive(X[0:int(len(X)/2)])[0] + ((len(X)-int(len(X)/2))/len(X))*mv_recursive(X[int(len(X)/2):len(X)])[0]
        var = mv_recursive(X[0:int(len(X)/2)])[1] + mv_recursive(X[int(len(X)/2):len(X)])[1] + ((int(len(X)/2)*(len(X)-int(len(X)/2)))/len(X))*(mv_recursive(X[0:int(len(X)/2)])[0]-mv_recursive(X[int(len(X)/2):len(X)])[0])*(mv_recursive(X[0:int(len(X)/2)])[0]-mv_recursive(X[int(len(X)/2):len(X)])[0])
    return mu, var
```

The above comes from the following realization:

[image]
[image]

How could one tackle the same problem for a stream of integers of unknown length (online mean calculation), using recursion and D&C?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: D&C on a stream does not make sense. Where is this question coming from ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust it comes from an uni assignment, specifically it says:

The recursive divide-and-conquer scheme for computing the mean and the variance of a stream can be adapted, so that an online computation (where the total stream length may not be known at the beginning) becomes possible. Implement this computation using the following function template (X is a list):

Comment: So you must include that recursive divide-and-conquer scheme in the question, otherwise there is nothing that we can adapt.

Comment: Sorry, added it now. @YvesDaoust

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have also added the general formulas

Comment: I wouldn't call a function with a 152-character line especially "easy". Also, this implementation ends up doing a lot of duplicate work, since it calls `mv_recursive` multiple times with the same arguments.

Comment: (On that note, [this reformulation](https://gist.github.com/akx/efe8c2db5569d6647f77985ea633f82a) is about 32,000 times faster on my machine than the original for a 200-item list.)

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on how to do the online approach?

Comment: The last row of the formulas hints you how to compute online, incrementally. But neither D&C nor recursion make sense for an online version.